# Exception: URL fetch failure for cifar10 dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've written a small python 2.8 set of code where I'm attempting to read the cifar10 images, but consistently get an Exception error. Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import datasets
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import cifar10
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()

"""
my error messages:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bmimi\anaconda3\envs\tf2.8\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 277, in get_file
    
urlretrieve(origin, fpath, dl_progress)
  File "C:\Users\bmimi\anaconda3\envs\tf2.8\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 82, in urlretrieve
    
response = urlopen(url, data)
  File "C:\Users\bmimi\anaconda3\envs\tf2.8\lib\urllib\request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\bmimi\anaconda3\envs\tf2.8\lib\urllib\request.py", line 517, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Users\bmimi\anaconda3\envs\tf2.8\lib\urllib\request.py", line 539, in _open
    return self._call_chain(self.handle_open, 'unknown',
  File "C:\Users\bmimi\anaconda3\envs\tf2.8\lib\urllib\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\bmimi\anaconda3\envs\tf2.8\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1413, in unknown_open
    raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: https>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bmimi\PycharmProjects\my_first_project\test.py", line 27, in <module>
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()
  File "C:\Users\bmimi\anaconda3\envs\tf2.8\lib\site-packages\keras\datasets\cifar10.py", line 79, in load_data
    
path = get_file(
  File "C:\Users\bmimi\anaconda3\envs\tf2.8\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\data_utils.py", line 281, in get_file
    
raise Exception(error_msg.format(origin, e.errno, e.reason))
Exception: URL fetch failure on https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar-10-python.tar.gz: None -- unknown url type: https
Downloading data from https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar-10-python.tar.gz

Process finished with exit code 1
"""
```

I am using Pycharm Community editor, python ver. 2.8 and Tensorflow ver. 2.8.

Am I misusing the tf code our is there something else wrong??
Thank for any help,
Bob

Comment: There is no python 2.8. Please edit your post to include what version you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is caused by the support of the *version* of `Python` that you are running, since if you do it in a more recent one `(3.7)` it does not return any error

```py
import tensorflow as tf # ver 2.x
print(tf.version)
from tensorflow.keras.datasets.cifar10 import load_data # dataset

(x_train, y_train), (x_val, y_val) = load_data()
```

...

```
<module 'tensorflow._api.v2.version' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/_api/v2/version/__init__.py'>
Downloading data from https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar-10-python.tar.gz
170500096/170498071 [==============================] - 11s 0us/step
170508288/170498071 [==============================] - 11s 0us/step
```

Comment: Sorry but I provided the wrong Python version. I have version 3.9.0 loaded and am using Windows 10. I seem to load the MNIST dataset with no problem, but cannot seem to load the CIFAR10 dataset.

Comment: Could there be an incompatibility between tf 2.8 and Python 3.9?

Comment: it may be that the problem resides due to the version of tensorflow that you have, try to downgrading it to a lower one, example `pip install tensorflow==1.15.0` as it appears in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64081325/error-while-importing-datasets-from-cifar10-py), if you need help with real examples you can visit this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/datasets/cifar10/load_data) and [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/xla/tutorials/autoclustering_xla)